# How can I save button state in recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Hello I have an horizontal recyclerview which contains some products, where in the plus button I add the products to shopping cart and after product is added the icon changes. I did this, but my problem is to save the state of this button, because when I navigate between fragmets/activities and when app starts button remains unchanged. Here what I have:

[image]

The code in my adapter is:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArtikujtViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Artikujt mArtikull = artikujt.get(position);

        String mArtikullName = mArtikull.getEmertimet();
        holder.artikullName.setText(mArtikullName);
        String mArtikullCmimi = mArtikull.getCmimi().toString();
        holder.artikullCmimi.setText(mArtikullCmimi+" Leke");

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ProductDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("positon", artikujt.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("mArtikullName", mArtikullName);
            intent.putExtra("mArtikullCmimi", mArtikullCmimi);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });

        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext
                .getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();

        // using shared preferences to save the state
        if (preferences.contains(ITEMS_PREF)) {
            holder.addItems.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                    R.drawable.ic_check_black, 0);
            holder.addItems.setEnabled(false);
        } else {

        }

        holder.addItems.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());
            if (artikullObject != null) {
                artikullObject.add(mArtikull);
                String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
                mEditor.apply();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Artikujt> arrayArtikuj = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayArtikuj.add(mArtikull);
                Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>() {}.getType();
                String s = gson.toJson(arrayArtikuj, listOfTestObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", s);
                mEditor.apply();
            }

             holder.addItems.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
              R.drawable.ic_check_black, 0);

            //======================================================================================
            // Display a toast message
            final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.shtuar_ne_shporte, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(toast::cancel, 1000);
            //======================================================================================

            assert artikullObject != null;
            count_key = artikullObject.size();

            String cartCount = String.valueOf(count_key);
            Intent my_intent = new Intent("msg");
            my_intent.putExtra("cart_count", cartCount);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(my_intent);

            v.setEnabled(false);
        });

    }
```

I searched a lot about it and the solution could be using shared preferences to save the state, with sharedprerences.contains(preferences_id) but I'm confused here. Does anyone have any suggestion how can I achieve this or which could be possible solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I am assuming that you want to keep the `button` as it was after clicking it:**

**If that is your problem, yes we will use `shared prefrences`:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArtikujtViewHolder holder, int position) {

//the item
final Artikujt mArtikull = artikujt.get(position);

..........
..........

//read the prefrences
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Button", MODE_PRIVATE);
String state = pref.getString(String.valueOf(position)+"pressed", "no");

if(state.equals("yes")){

//the button must be pressed, make it pressed (check mark icon)

//change the icon
holder.addItems.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.ic_check_black, 0);

holder.addItems.setEnabled(false);

}else{
//the button must not be pressed, make it not pressed (default add icon)

//change the icon
holder.addItems.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.ic_add_icon, 0);

holder.addItems.setEnabled(true);
}


//after clicking the add icon

holder.addItems.setOnClickListener(v -> {

//save to preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Button", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString(String.valueOf(position)+ "pressed", "yes");
editor.apply();


//change the icon
holder.addItems.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.ic_check_black, 0);
            //======================================================================================
// Display a toast message
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.shtuar_ne_shporte, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(toast::cancel, 1000);
            //======================================================================================

assert artikullObject != null;
count_key = artikullObject.size();

String cartCount = String.valueOf(count_key);
Intent my_intent = new Intent("msg");
my_intent.putExtra("cart_count", cartCount);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(my_intent);

v.setEnabled(false);

});


}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the most cases saving the state of the button in the model list is enough. However,when an user change its fragment or activity, there is possibility of that you model list could be destroyed by the system because of memory usage. For this case you have choose whether persist your data using sharedpref,file,db etc or keeping your data in a store whose lifespan is longer than the activity or fragment. It seems that the page you share is related to your app's main functionality so you should keep your data in a repository whose scope is dependent on the app scope. I recommend you to look at mvvm architecture and repository pattern.